# pipe output to file to function

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I have a function, call it `a()`, that writes something to a file and another function, call it `b()` that reads something from a file. I would like to pipe the output of `a()` and pipe it into `b()` without a file ever actually being created. Is this possible?

(for the curious: `a()` is [`aws.s3::save_object()`](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3), which saves an object from an S3 bucket to disk and `b()` is [`feather::read_feather()`](https://github.com/wesm/feather), which reads in a feather file into a tibble.)

Comment: Can you use get_object() from aws.s3 to just get the object from S3 to workspace?

Comment: And how would I then feed that through `read_feather()`?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You shouldn't need to save a file and read in back into R.

Comment: I'm trying to read in a feather file that's located in an S3 bucket without it ever hitting disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `save_object()` is a file string containing the path to the saved file, so you can just nest your function calls:

```
library("aws.s3")
library("feather")
read_feather(save_object("objectkey", "bucket"))
```

If feather is capable of reading from a connection (seems like it isn't, but if it could), you can skip the disk I/O and use `get_object()` instead:

```
read_feather(rawConnection(get_object("objectkey", "bucket")))
```

(Note: I'm the maintainer of the aws.s3 package.)